# Variable returned from function reset to zero

Tags: c++, function, return

This is a program that will read the numbers in an input file and put them into an array, and then sort them ascending and print them into an output file.

There are no errors while compiling, but when the program is running it will correctly count the number of numbers in the file and store them until the `numsize` is returned to the mail function when it becomes zero.

I tested this by having the loop print what `numsize` was every time, it isn't until the `main()` function when it changes back to zero.

My only guess is that I am not returning the variable correctly, or maybe not declaring it correctly

```
int store (int arg[20], int numsize, istream& infile) 
{
  numsize = 0;
  if(numsize<20)
  {
    infile >> arg[numsize];
  }
  while(!infile.eof())
  {
    numsize++;
    if(numsize<20)
    {
        cout << numsize;
        infile >> arg[numsize];
    }
  } 
  return numsize;   
}

int printarray (int arg[20], int numsize, ostream& outfile) 
{
  for (int i = 0; i<= numsize; i++ )
  {
   outfile << arg[i] << endl;
  }     
  return 0;
}

int main ()
{
  int arg[20];
  int numsize;

  std::string input_filename, output_filename;
  ofstream out_file;
  ifstream in_file;

  cout << "Please enter name of input file: ";
  cin >> input_filename;
  in_file.open(input_filename.c_str());
  if (!in_file)
  {
    cout << "Could not open input file\n";
    return 0;
  }

  cout << "Please enter name of output file: ";
  cin >> output_filename;
  out_file.open(output_filename.c_str());
  if (!out_file)
  {
    cout << "Could not open output file\n";
    return 0;
  }

  store(arg, numsize, in_file);
  cout << numsize << "numbers were read from the input file" << endl;
  printarray(arg, numsize, out_file);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `numsize = 0;
if(numsize<20)`? Also, your loop increments `numsize` before reading anything if this `if` doesn't pass, meaning your array's first element is used uninitialized. Finally, your [`while (!eof())` is wrong.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). You never ensure the integer was actually read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two ways to fix it:

1) If you don't want to allow the function `store()` to change it's second argument, just replace this line:

```
store(arg, numsize, in_file);
```

by this line:

```
numsize = store(arg, numsize, in_file);
```

2) Also you can just replace this line

```
int store (int arg[20], int numsize, istream& infile)
```

by this line

```
int store (int arg[20], int& numsize, istream& infile)
```

(in this case your function `store()` will be able to change the value `numsize`)

Also I'd recommend you to change the function `store()` this way:

```
int store (int arg[20], istream& infile) 
{
  int numsize = 0;
  while((numsize<20) && (infile >> arg[numsize]))
  {
    numsize++;
    cout << numsize;
  } 
  return numsize;   
}
```

And to call it this way:

```
numsize = store(arg, in_file);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since `numsize` is passed by value, any modifications to it inside `store` are discarded upon exiting. You need to assign the return value back to `numsize`:

```
numsize = store(arg, numsize, in_file);
```

**Note:** You use `numsize` in your `store` function as if it were a local variable, because you assign it zero right away. Do not pass it at all:

```
int store (int arg[20], istream& infile)  {
    int numsize = 0;
    while(numsize < 20 && (infile >> arg[numsize])) {
        numsize++;
        cout << numsize;
    }
    return numsize;
}
```

Also do not use `infile.eof()`, this is an incorrect usage pattern

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `numsize` by reference in `store()`.
Change

```
int store (int arg[20], int numsize, istream& infile)
```

to

```
int store (int arg[20], int& numsize, istream& infile)
```

Also, either change `store()` return type to `void`, or return an int from it (i.e. `numsize`?)

Answer (score 3):

You should write at least like

```
numsize = store(arg, numsize, in_file);
```

It would be more correct to declare the function like

```
size_t store ( int arg[], size_t n, istream& infile);
```

where the parameter `n` denotes the number of elements in the array. Otherwise the function will be depend on the magic unknown number 20.

Also the loop in the function is incorrect. The function can place into the array the last number twice because the condition `eof` is checked after a number is stored in the array.

The function implementation can look like

```
size_t store( int arg[], size_t n, istream& infile ) 
{
    size_t i = 0;
    int value;

    while( i < n && infile >> value ) arg[i++] = value;

    return i;
}
```

and called like

```
size_t numsize;

//...

numsize = store( arg, sizeof( arg ) / sizeof( *arg ), in_file );
```

Correspondingly the function `printarray` should be defined like

```
void printarray( int arg[], size_t numsize, ostream& outfile) 
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < numsize; i++ )
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
       outfile << arg[i] << endl;
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are calling the `store` function in the main function, then try to save the value of the returned variable `numsize` from the function `store`. You may try the following code:

```
numsize = store(arg, numsize, in_file);
```